# gsutil cp in python via os.system

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cp, gsutil, os.system

I want to copy a local file to google cloud bucket. I am able to do that using `gsutil cp` in command line. But I want to do that in python, hence to run the similar command in python I use the following line:

`os.system('gsutil cp '+ '/MY-LOCAL-FILE-NAME' +' gs://My-Bucket-Name')`

It sends the file to bucket but it's an empty file!!!
I also tried python subprocess but same problem.
I think the problem is string concatenations. When I use the whole string it works and sends the file to bucket but when I concatenate substrings in "subprocess" or "os.system" , it just sends an empty file, this is so weird, any idea about this???

Comment: The fact that file is in the same path as your python script means nothing. The *current working directory* means everything.

Comment: Thank you, I actually know that. E.g., when I use simple os.system(' cp ...') command it works but for os.system('gsutil cp...') I get the above errors, I don't know why with gsutil it doesn't work?

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't use the Python library for this purpose? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Comment: I agree with @ScottMcC , using GCS libraries for Python would be way easier. Is there a reason for using command line?

Comment: I want my code to be platform-independent as much as possible that's the reason I try to avoid using GCS libraries. Actually I found out this is the problem because of python/subprocess/os.system string concatenation. When I use the whole string without any concatenation (+) it works and sends the file to bucket but when I concatenate substrings together, it doesn't work and it just sends an empty file to bucket, it's so weird any idea about the reason? Thanks

Comment: If I have two commands can I still use os.system? For example I first have a gcloud auth activate-service-account command and then a gsutil command after that. Will the second command open a new window and ignore the first command?

Answer (score 1):

From the Gcloud github you have [snippets](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/tree/master/samples/snippets) where one is of interest for you :

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
"""Uploads a file to the bucket."""
     storage_client = storage.Client()
     bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
     blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

     blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
    source_file_name,
    destination_blob_name))
```

Comment: broken link is broken.

Comment: Indeed, the snippets have just been moved. Updated the link. Tx